# SharePoint 2010: Access Denied to Admin user

Tags: sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping

I have SharePoint 2010 web application with following Alternate Access Mapping defined:

**Internal URL** |             **Zone** |         **Public URL**

http://exampleURL:8080 |   Default Zone | http://exampleURL:8080

https://traininglink.com | Internet |    https://traininglink.com

http://traininglink.com | Internet  |   https://traininglink.com

http://internaltraining.com | Extranet | http://internaltraining.com

Application has claims authentication implemented. I am able to access `default.aspx` using first three URL using Admin user(Domain admin user for first link and claims admin user for last 3). But when I try to access using last url using same user, I am getting access denied error. On checking fiddler, I found that for last URL, I am getting `404` response for certain files in "_layouts/images" folder. These are OOTB SharePoint images used in Default.aspx pages(/_layouts/images/fgimg.png).

Plese guide.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the IIS Settings and found that the `"Images"` virtual directory was not mapped for the `url` `http://internaltraining.com` in IIS. Once that was done, everything works fine.

Comment: it is very strange, you dont need to map the SP virtual directories. it all needs is just the extending the web application. looks like you made some changes at the IIS after extending...

Comment: There was some issue with one front end server which messed up everything.

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't recommend changing the settings manually, you have to run the configuration wizard and or try detaching/attaching to the server farm which is always a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

**I would recommend checking the below steps to identify the cause of the problem.**

1. Does the Master page or the page used by the hope page is checked-out?
2. Check the permission level policy May have been modified in the web application settings on the Central administration.
3. If the above mentioned approaches are not helping you to resolve the issue, please go through the ULS log.

Comment: I had already tried all the above approaches but cannot come to concrete root cause and solution